# Как упростить условие

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

Есть "программа" в которой есть классы Viking, Wizzard Assasin, далее должны формироваться две команды red_team и blue_team. В каждой команде может быть 3 участника dude, dude2, dude3 задача такая рандомно назначить переменным dude/2/3 классы. 
Я реализовал это так:

```
chance = randint (1, 3)
If chance == 1:
    dude = Viking (name = 'Red Viking')
if chance == 2:
    dude = Wizzard (name = 'Red Wizzard')
if chance == 3:
    dude = Assasin  (name = 'Red Assasin')
red_taem.append (dude.name)

chance = randint (1, 3)
If chance == 1:
    dude2 = Viking (name = 'Red Viking')
if chance == 2:
    dude2 = Wizzard (name = 'Red Wizzard')
if chance == 3:
    dude2 = Assasin  (name = 'Red Assasin')
red_team.append (dude2.name)

chance = randint (1, 3)
If chance == 1:
    dude3 = Viking (name = 'Red Viking')
if chance == 2:
    dude3 = Wizzard (name = 'Red Wizzard')
if chance == 3:
    dude3 = Assasin  (name = 'Red Assasin')
red_team.append (dude3.name)
```

И вот этот вот ужас только для одной команды из трех участников! А если бы их было 20?

Собственно вопрос: как это вот это все упростить? Чтобы не писать 100 000 сторк кода.

П.С. Если предлагаете вариант решения пожалуйста объясните мне как ваш вариант будет работать.

Классы: тут на самом деле та еще белеберда...

```
class Viking:
    def __init__(self,  name):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = 100
        self.energy  = 100
        self.damage = 30
        self.block = 15
        self.role = 'tank'

class Assasin:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = 100
        self.energy  = 100
        self.damage = 30
        self.block = 15
        self.role = 'ass'

class Wizzard:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = 100
        self.energy  = 100
        self.damage = 30
        self.block = 15
        self.role = 'tank'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция [random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) возвращает список из `k` случайно выбранных элементов из `population`.

Пример:

```
from random import choices

def build_team(N, color):
    dudes = [Viking(name=f'{color} Viking'), 
             Wizzard(name=f'{color} Wizzard'), 
             Assasin(name=f'{color} Assasin')]
    return choices(dudes, k=N)

red_team = build_team(3, 'Red')
blue_team = build_team(3, 'Blue')
```

---

**UPDATE:**

чтобы при выводе объекта класса на печать получить имя (`self.name`) - определите метод `__repr__()` для всех ваших классов:

```
class Viking:
    def __init__(self,  name):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = 100
        self.energy  = 100
        self.damage = 30
        self.block = 15
        self.role = 'tank'

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

v = Viking(name='Red Viking')
print(v)
# Red Viking
```

Comment: Отлично! Это то что нужно! Большое человеческое спасибо ))) но есть одно но. Если сделать ptint (red_team) то мы получим список обьектов, а хотелось бы список имен...

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar, как у вас объявлены классы `Vikinng`, `Wizzard`, `Assasin`?

Comment: Закинул описания в вопрос

Comment: Через переменную все работает, а вот через выше описанную ф-цию build_team (даже с методом __str__) выдает обьекты (

Comment: Все получилось реализовать через repr еще раз большое спасибо. )))